# HCE does not repond to

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, hce, contactless-smartcard

I use `MFRC522` as the reader, while Sony Xperia M4 is executing Google HCE sample.

`RATS` is OK, then the reader sends the frame for AID:

`02 00 A4 04 00 07 F0 01 02 03 04 05 06 crc1 crc2`

HCE logs the incoming frame and response it correctly.
However, the reader does not get any data returned. Why?